# Threading and recursion problem using Sqlite with sqlalchemy in a flask api called by react app

Tags: python, reactjs, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a web app using Flask for API and data access and React with Material-UI for UI.  In general, I have been successful in using React components in the UI, getting the data from Sqlite using the Flask API.  The Flask app is set to proxy unknown requests to the Flask API.

I'm not able to create a code sandbox because I can't add dependencies for Flask or for SQLAlchemy.

The app was really almost complete; I was able to get data from several different tables using Flask and the API. Then I added a data filter selection component and a call to the API to get the last filter selection from a Settings table and that simple call is breaking in two ways:

1. The API call to getFilter is being called repeatedly. I can't find what to do to stop it.  Loading the value is a change which calls the onChange which reloads the settings which causes a change. I am sure this is a bug in how I'm implementing it but I don't know what to do to fix it. The event handler is in the grandparent component, app.js, of the FilterSelector, where the change occurs.  The error repeats until I get an error that Python could not create any more threads and then the Flask app is hung and has to be closed by closing the PowerShell window I am running it in, after which, the React app gives an http 500 that it could not proxy to the Flask app.
2. The calls to the API are coming in on different threads - a new thread is created for every second call and Sqlite is complaining about objects created in one thread not being available in another thread:

```
**sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 4852 and this is thread id 2824.  
[SQL: SELECT settings.settingname AS settings_settingname, settings.settingvalue AS settings_settingvalue  
FROM settings  
WHERE settings.settingname = ?]  
[parameters: [immutabledict({})]]  
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405) // Werkzeug Debugger**
```

I don't know if the recursion is due to the thread error or if the threading error is due to the recursion.  I wouldn't expect Python or sqlalchemy to create multiple threads for these calls.

I wish I could create a codeplaypen for this but I can't so here's the code:

React Code:

This line at the end of package.json lets the React app proxy to the API:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Users from './Components/Users/Users';

export default function UserManager() {

  const [Filter, setFilter] = useState('all');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/getFilter').then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
      console.log(new Date() + "Filter useEffect data = " + data);
      setFilter(data);
      console.log(new Date() + "Filter useEffect set to: " + Filter)
      });
    }
  )  
  const filterChanged = (event, selectedFilter) => {
    alert('app.js filter changed! Filter=' + Filter + ' and selectedFilter=' + selectedFilter);
    setFilter(selectedFilter);
  };
  
  return (  
          <div>
            <Users 
            filterChanged={filterChanged.bind(this)} 
            filter={ Filter } 
          />
          </div>
   )
}
```

Users.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FilterSelector from './FilterSelector'

export class Users extends Component {
    
    
    render() {
        const filter = this.props.filter;
        console.log(this.props.filter)
        console.log("Users render - " + this.props.filter);
        return (<FilterSelector filter={filter} filterChanged={this.props.filterChanged.bind(this)}/>)
    }
}

export default Users
```

FilterSelector.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';

export default function FilterSelector(props) {

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Filter</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="filters" name="filter1" value={ props.filter } onChange={ props.filterChanged }>
        <FormControlLabel value="favorites" control={<Radio />} label="Favorites" />
        <FormControlLabel value="included" control={<Radio />} label="Included" />
        <FormControlLabel value="all" control={<Radio />} label="All" />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Flask API Code:
api.py:

```
import time
from flask import Flask
import userdata
import json
import datetime

import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/getFilter')
#sample: http://localhost:5000/api/getFilter
def getFilter():
    print ("In getFilter")
    #return "favorites"
    filter = userdata.getSetting('filter')

    print ("{0}In api getFilter().  Filterdata from db is: {1}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), filter))
    
    if filter is None:
        #userdata.updateSetting('channelfilter', 'all')
        filter = 'favorites' 
    print ("In getfilter2")
    return filter

"""
@app.route('/api/saveFilter/<filterValue>')
#sample: http://localhost:5000/api/saveFilter/favorites
def saveFilter(filterValue):
    userdata.updateSetting('filter', filterValue)
    return filterValue
"""
#Below route is for development testing only, remove for production.
@app.route('/api/getUsers')
#sample: http://localhost:5000/api/getUsers
def getUsersFromDB():
    return json.loads(userdata.GetUsers())

@app.route('/api/getUsers/<filter>')
#sample: http://localhost:5000/api/getUsers/favorites
def getUsersFromDBFiltered(filter):
    print("In getUsersFiltered. filter = {0}".format(filter))
    return json.loads(userdata.GetUsers())

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

userdata.py - shows there is no data changing or updating code so nothing is "created" in the DB in any thread.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKeyConstraint, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy import PrimaryKeyConstraint, Integer, String, Boolean, DateTime, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import text
import json
import os

Base = declarative_base()
Engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data/users.db')
Base.metadata.bind = Engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
session = DBSession()

class Settings(Base):
    __tablename__ = "settings"
    settingname = Column(String(80), primary_key=True)
    settingvalue = Column(String(80), nullable=False)


def ResultSetQueryToJson(resultSet):
    print ('Not Yet Implemented.')
    return resultSet
        
def ResultSetDeclarativeToJson(resultSet):
    jsontext = "{{\n\t\"{0}\": [".format(resultSet[0].__table__.name)

    for datarow in resultSet:
        rowsdata = ""
        columncount = len(datarow.__table__.columns)
        if jsontext.endswith("}"):
            jsontext += ","
        jsontext += "{\n"
        for c in datarow.__table__.columns:
            columncount -= 1
            rowsdata = rowsdata + "\n\t\t\"{0}\": \"{1}\"".format(c.key, getattr(datarow, c.key))
            if columncount > 0:
                rowsdata += ","
        jsontext += rowsdata
        jsontext += "\n\t}"
    return jsontext + "]\n}"


def getSettings():
    print("Start getSettings())")
    return session.query(Settings).all()

def getSetting(sname):
    print("Starting userdata.getSetting() for {0}.".format(sname))
    result = session.query(Settings).filter(Settings.settingname == sname).one_or_none()
    print ("in getSetting.  Query Result = {0}".format(result))
    if result is not None:
        svalue = result.settingvalue
        print('Got setting {0}: {1}'.format(sname, svalue))
        return svalue
    return None


"""
def updateSetting(sname, svalue):
    setting = Settings()
    setting.settingname = sname
    setting.settingvalue = svalue
    session.merge(setting)
    session.commit()

"""


class Apps(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'apps'
    appid = Column(String(24), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    vendor = Column(String(80), nullable=True)
    version = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    isDeleted = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    userid = Column(String(80), primary_key=True)
    lastname = Column(String(40), nullable=False)
    firstname = Column(String(40), nullable=False)
    emailaddress = Column(String(80), nullable=False)

def ReflectTableColumns(DbEngine, meta, targetTable):
    tableschema = Table(targetTable, meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=DbEngine)
    cols = dict()
    for c in tableschema.columns:
        print("{0}\t|\t{1}".format(c.name, c.type))
        cols[c.name] = c.type
    
    return cols

def GetUsers():
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
    session = DBSession()
    results = session.query(Users).all()
    ShowTableData(results, 'users')
    return ResultSetDeclarativeToJson(results)
```

I've made sure no other instances of anything are touching the database file; closing all VSCode windows, all explorer windows, even rebooting and then starting the React and Flask apps anew.  It's very odd that this code only causes the issue an none of my other database calling code does.

I know it's a complex scenario to evaluate without a codesandbox but I will definitely be appreciative of any help.  I know appreciation isn't as good a beer but it's all I got for now.

Comment: `session = DBSession()` in module scope is a source for threading issues, because `Session` instances are not thread-safe. Either create the sessions in a suitable scope, or if you use threads as for example request scope, use [scoped sessions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html). A short recap: engines are handy shells for connection pools, which are thread-safe. Connections on the other hand are not, so don't share those between threads. Sessions aren't thread-safe either, so no sharing. So create engines in module scope, and the session factory, but not sessions.

Comment: That was it.  It resolved the recursive issue and the threading.  Thank you.